# DKIM for subdomain in Cloudflare

Tags: dns-zone, dkim, dns-hosting

I have example.com configured cPanel and I do not use it as mail server. I have created new subdomain in Cloudflare called mailer.example.com and installed Virtualmin on new Ubuntu server with hostname as mailer.example.com.

I have setup MX record for mailer.example.com in Cloudflare. It is working fine.

Now I have generated DKIM for my host called mailer.example.com.

Its selector is 202111.

Now I have added TXT record in Cloudflare:

```
Name = 202111._domainkey.mailer
```

and

```
Content = "<DKIM value given by Virtualmin>"
```

But in mail-tester.com and MxToolbox, I am getting that no DKIM record found for my domain as well in DNS lookup, I can not see any text record for my domain called mailer.example.com.

I think I am missing something but not getting idea about it. Let me know if someone can help me for same.

Comment: Install DKIM into the domain it belongs to. It doesn't have to do anything with the name of the host with mailer. If the domain is `example.org`, your key has to be published as `selector._domainkey.example.org`, where the selector is *configured* on the mailer host together with the corresponding private key to sign with. // Also note, questions involving web hosting control panels are off-topic because they [customize their systems so that standard system administration methods no longer apply](https://meta.serverfault.com/questions/8055).

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov In this case, I think the question is about properly configuring a record and the issue with admin panel questions is how they configure the server, itself. Also, please consider posting your comment as an answer, as it appears to solve the problem.

Comment: @Paul I see in this case the problem has probably nothing to do with those panels. This is precisely why I bothered to even comment. However, the discussion under the link in the closure reason calls for closure and reopen if the question was reformulated in a way it doesn't mentions panels even incidentally.

Answer (score 0):

If you use custom selector name, you need check on the mail header on recipient.

Mail-tester.com just check the default ones

Comment: Mail-tester will test the headers in the received email. There is no standardized default selector to test against.